# Want to add spacing between buttons

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a simple task to add space  between buttons in a dialog box like in the example code below obtained from http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html. Just imagine that there is more than 1 button is this example. Like save, delete, cancel, confirm.

```
bootbox.dialog({
        title: "This is a form in a modal.",
        message: '<div class="row">  ' +
            '<div class="col-md-12"> ' +
            '<form class="form-horizontal"> ' +
            '<div class="form-group"> ' +
            '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Name</label> ' +
            '<div class="col-md-4"> ' +
            '<input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control input-md"> ' +
            '<span class="help-block">Here goes your name</span> </div> ' +
            '</div> ' +
            '<div class="form-group"> ' +
            '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="awesomeness">How awesome is this?</label> ' +
            '<div class="col-md-4"> <div class="radio"> <label for="awesomeness-0"> ' +
            '<input type="radio" name="awesomeness" id="awesomeness-0" value="Really awesome" checked="checked"> ' +
            'Really awesome </label> ' +
            '</div><div class="radio"> <label for="awesomeness-1"> ' +
            '<input type="radio" name="awesomeness" id="awesomeness-1" value="Super awesome"> Super awesome </label> ' +
            '</div> ' +
            '</div> </div>' +
            '</form> </div>  </div>',
        buttons: {
            success: {
                label: "Save",
                className: "btn-success",
                callback: function () {
                    var name = $('#name').val();
                    var answer = $("input[name='awesomeness']:checked").val()
                    Example.show("Hello " + name + ". You've chosen <b>" + answer + "</b>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

I would like to know how to increase the spacing between the buttons so that they are placed more far apart and look spacious and the UI of the dialog box is more beautiful. I am not so good at these stuff. I have searched a lot. Please help me. Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Please give some code and live example if possible. Thank you again.

Comment: Can you set up a `jsfiddle` which includes your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Give the buttons margins and/or padding. http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/margins/

Comment: Use CSS and give your button classes the style you want. i.e. `.btn-success { margin: 0 10px; }`. You could do the same for any other buttons.

Comment: where to add the style - outside the script tags or inside ? thanks zgood

Comment: @AdminRelative You would put it in your sites CSS file. And you can make it more generic like this: `.modal-footer button { margin-left:10px; }`

Comment: Thanks a lot zgood - it works ! Really thanks a lot ~

Comment: Thanks all others too for your help `

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `&nbsp;` or `margin` property to add spacing between buttons on a webpage.

## Using `&nbsp;` :

You can use `&nbsp;`  between the closing tag of first button and opening tag of second button just like shown below.

```
<button>Button 1</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button>Button 2</button>
```

you can add more `&nbsp;` for adding more space.

## Using `margin` attribute :

You can add spacing between two objects by adding `margin` on its sides. The CSS code is as follows,

```
.btn_name{
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

to add space on left side or you can add space on right side by using the following code,

```
.btn_name{
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Solved

Answer (score 2):

Another soltuion that may be quite elegant is to use `{" "}`. It is more readable than the *cryptic* `&nbsp;`. :)

```
<button>Button 1</button> {" "} <button>Button 2</button>
```