# How to add space between create button and a success message that will show at the bottom after creating?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

In my form, I have the following JSX written with React and after I create with the button, the success message will touch the button at the bottom, leaving no space. Is there anyway to add that space between? Thanks again.

```
      <button className="btn btn-primary">Create a hat</button>
    </div >
  </form >
  <div className={successClass} id="success-message">
    You have created a new hat!
  </div>
```

I tried googling methods to add properties into the button and message but nothing seems to split them apart.

Comment: Two things ! , You can either add a padding-top/bottom css to the message div .. or  add the same css to the form element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want to add spacing between buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198170/want-to-add-spacing-between-buttons)

Comment: Try to use `{' '}` in JSX code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `padding-top` to the success message div.

```
<button className="btn btn-primary">Create a hat</button>
                </div>
              </form>
                <div className={successClass} id="success-message"
style={{paddingTop :"2rem"}}
>
                    You have created a new hat!
                </div>

`
```

Comment: hey, so there is a syntax error with the code

Comment: I've updated the answer, try now

Answer (score 0):

```
 </form>
&nbsp;
 <div className={successClass} id="success-message">
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to position elements is by use of `CSS`, avoid things like `{' '}`

Second, make your page structure clear for example

```
<div class="form-wrapper" style="padding: 10px; margin-bottom:4px;">
   <form>
   <!-- put your create button here -->
   </form>
</div>

<div class="success-msg-wrapper" style="padding: 10px;">
   <!-- put your message div here -->
</div>
```

Finally, make use of **class-based styling** instead of **inline css** for better maintainability of the code.